# how to set all links(href) in the page to "#" with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

how to set all links(href) in the page to "#" with javascript

Comment: Do you want to set all `<link>` elements' `href` attribute to '#' or all anchor (`<a>`) elements' `href` attribute to '#'?

Comment: Why would you do something this evil?  This breaks my beloved middle click.

Comment: @Cory Larson, It doesn't make much sens to set a `<link>`'s `href` to `#`, does it?

Comment: Don't do that, please.  It kills the ability to view the link with a mouse over, and kills the ability to middle or right click the link.  Instead, bind to the on-click event for the link and return false to prevent the browser from following the link...

Comment: @strager: No, it doesn't make sense, and I know what he meant, but it's not __crystal__ clear. A beginner finding their way to this post might be confused when the OP writes "links" and really meant "hyperlinks" or "anchors".

Comment: @Cory Larson, I don't think many web programmers would think `<link>` the first time they read "set links (href) in the page".  I don't think many beginning web programmers would think that, either.

Comment: Instead of arguing over pedantry, how about upvoting my answer to the top so the OP doesn't commit this evil? ;)

Comment: @Everyone: Ok, I'll stop being a semantics Nazi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the getElementsByTagName() method to get the tags, then loop through them to set the property.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var link in links)
{
    links[link].href = "#";
}
```

EDIT: To satisfy a non "foreach" method.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) 
{
    links[i].href = "#";
}
```

Comment: `for..in` is bad practice for [pseudo]arrays.

Comment: @strager - documentation? reason?

Comment: Don't use `for( i in ... )` to loop over array-like objects, e.g. NodeLists.

Comment: Also, your code is wrong: the inner part of the loop should read `links[link].href`, not `link.href`.  `link` is the index.

Comment: @Joel, a) it's slow (Really slow) b) It'll loop over any items added to the prototype (which isn't what you want).

Comment: @Joel Etherton, See [Why is using "for ...in" with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Comment: @strager, @J-P thanks for the references. I will read. @strager, no var link creates the reference not an index (this array is not associative). I've used similar code to generate elements.

Comment: @Joel Etherton, Blasphemy!  `link` is the index.  I just checked.

Comment: You're not declaring `i` and you should *cache* the `length` of the array in another var.

Answer (score 6):

**DON'T CHANGE HREF TO #**

Set the onclick function to return false instead.

This will have the same effect, whilst allowing greater usability.

Here's a quick example (using jQuery, but works with anything):

```
jQuery('a').click( doStuff );

function doStuff()
{
    // ...function body...

    return false;
}
```

This works because the value you return from an *onX* event function determines whether that event continues firing or stops. Return `true` to allow it to continue or `false` to stop it.

With `onclick` this means the click is stopped (so the link isn't followed) - however it still allows people to interact with the link via middle and right click (e.g. opening in new tab, adding to bookmarks, and so on)

For another example, with `onkeypress` you can return false to prevent the character typed from being added to an input control (for example, you could mimic the HTML5 `input="numeric"` control by having an `onkeypress` that returned false for any non-numeric characters).

Comment: Then don't use jQuery. The concept of returning true/false is core JavaScript. I don't bother remembering the two or three different ways of binding methods, so I used jQuery for simplicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
$('a').attr('href', '#');
```